# Simple prepared statement with COUNT(..) not working

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the following error with the following prepared statement code. Wondering what the reason is, since it all looks correct.

```
Notice: Connection failed: Prepared statement invalid: Operand should contain 1 column(s) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 58
```

Here's the code:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'myusers'); // this is confirmed to work for connecting
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    trigger_error('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
    die();
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) as count_u FROM Users WHERE (title=?, forename=?, surname=?)');
if (!$stmt) { // here, $stmt is false or such.
    trigger_error('Connection failed: Prepared statement invalid: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));
    die();
}
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is incorrect.  Hint:  `AND`.

Comment: Is `(title=?, forename=?, surname=?)` valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE title=?
  AND forename=?
  AND surname=?
```

Comment: Thank you, just some 'rusty with SQL' issue I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

use and / or in you where clause

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) as count_u FROM Users WHERE title=? and/or  forename=? and/or surname=?)');
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $title, $forename, $surname);
```